# Connection between the circular ring in Windows and the Circular disk in Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, desktop-computer

I have never owned a PC cause I am on a Mac for most of the time but I am planning to buy one — probably a workstation grade — and I have one query. I have seen and used many high end PCs (In Gaming Events, Friend's PC, etc.) and one thing I have noticed among all of them is that there's always a revolving circular ring no matter what you are doing or trying to open upload. Now since I'm a Mac guy, a circular disk in Mac means something's not right with your Mac or your Mac has slowed down due to some technical problem. So my question is does this statement apply to circular loading rings in Windows PCs too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUIs have always had “busy cursor” animations for the mouse cursor to indicate that the computer is busy and probably not handling your clicks right now.

Different versions of different OSes have had different triggers and thresholds for when they display the busy cursor.

Seeing a busy cursor doesn’t necessarily mean anything is broken on any OS. Of course, if it never goes away, something’s wrong.

Comment: But why should a busy cursor show up in a High End PC where every thing will load instantly. For example suppose I am rendering an 8K footage (Adobe Premiere) in an iMac Pro with 18 cores and it doesn't shows up the busy cursor even once cause your system is fast and on the other hand if you are working in the Windows version of AP the busy cursor constantly shows up to navigate through your Adobe Premiere Timeline inspite of having such a High End PC!

Comment: @sayan I think you should ask your Adobe Premiere question separately. Be sure to document exactly what hardware your Windows PC has, and try to use separate sentences instead of making onle long ungrammatical run-on sentence. :-)

Comment: Windows will show you the busy cursor just opening a folder on an SSD. It's a different paradigm.

Comment: @Tetsujin So it's a GUI problem, I guess? Nothing wrong with your hardware!

Comment: @Spiff Is there anyway to get rid of this busy cursor